# How do I make an empty stand for a different group instance?

Tags: groups

I have a set of group instances that pull data from a group linked in another file. I want to reset them to get their data from a group in the same file, so that I can animate their rotation.

My understanding is what I want to do is remap users for the empty, to a different group, however when I try to do that, the error shown is that this can't be done for a multi-user object.

I'm not clear on what is happening here. How can I remap these groups?

[image: screenshot of remap pop-up over outliner editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Group Instances* can actually be created [from any object type](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64064/dupligroups-and-snapping), but by default when inserted from the menu an *Empty* object is created.

Empty objects don't have any object data thus can't be "remapped" in the traditional sense. Group instances are stored instead as *Dupligroup* property on the object itself.

To change which group is being instanced by a certain object go to the *Properties Window > Object Tab > Duplication* and from the *Group* box pick the desired group.

To mass change on a large number of object select them all so that the object with the correct *Dupligroup* is active then use the *Link Menu* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> *Make Links > Dupligroup*.

[image]

Comment: I have to ask - why might one make a group instance out of another kind of object? And thanks.

Comment: It could be a placefolder. You could use its geometry as say, a bounding box, a visual guide or reference, as a snapping cage, or even a simplified version of said object for viewport performance reasons. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64064/dupligroups-and-snapping/