# Is there a way to replace an object in my scene with a different one?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Is there a way to replace one object position to another object position? and automatically match the scale? Any sort of addon or there is a way to do it? For example, I have a basic chair obj in the scene, however I downloaded a better chair, so I import the obj to the scene, is there a way I can just replace the downloaded chair obj to the basic obj with matching the scale and position?

Comment: There is a possibility to override, discussed i.a. on Blender artists, but I know nothing about actual **overwriting** Guess it's not possible.

Answer (score 11):

If the objects are all of the same type (mesh, curve, empty, etc) you can use the make links menu.

Select all objects you want to replace, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-Select the "master object" you want to replace with making sure it remains as *Active Object* (notice the brighter orange outline around it).

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> *Make links > Object Data*.

You can also access it from the *Object > Make Links > Object Data* menu in the 3DView header.

If objects are empties with duplicated collections use the *Make Links > Instance Collection* option instead.

[image]

Comment: Can you do this with collection instances? I have tons of proxy objects with various sizes, positions, and rotations that I would like replaced by my collection instance.

Comment: @CobyRandal Yes, you have to convert objects into empties, then link duplicates on the empties. See [Workaround#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64064/dupligroups-and-snapping/64107#64107)

Comment: I enjoyed your insights into the features lacking for CAD stuff in Blender and the custom snapping mesh is a good idea. Now I am looking for a Python script to convert my objects to empties, OR at least place empties inside my objects and make the objects the parents of the empties. Thanks!

Comment: I just replaced 383 Turbosquid model instances I ran through a rigid body sim with an original model. Thank you!

Comment: This didn't work when I tried to replace an Empty with a mesh object.

Comment: It only works between same type objects, obviously. If you have instances and wish to replace with objects, then turn the instances into objects of the same type first, for example by making duplicates real.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to copy *Location* and *Scale* values.
Assuming your objects have similar the proportions.

First, select your *target* object.
Second, select your *source* object.
Then click right mouse button and *Copy all to selected*.

[image]