# How to Link Materials

Tags: geometry

I have a geometry and 35 other similar shaped geometry.
I want to transfer the same material to correct faces from that source to other 35. How to do it?

Comment: Press F3 and search for "Link material", If they are similar and not same it will probably be needed to assign materials to correct faces manually

Comment: sir, they are exactly same looking objects.... It's a 3d model of a light bulb and i want to make it's outer thing glass and give emission to inner wire... But i have 35 of those how to do that ???

Comment: If they are same then it is easier to remove 34 of them, use material on the left one and create those 34 again with already existing materials... Link materials will only give them materials of 1 of the objects but it will not apply them or assign them... If you want to try it anyway, choose 1 light bulb... set material, select all others light bulb and the one with materials need to be active (orange) and do F3 - > link materials... it will give all objects two materials, glass and emit, but now you have to assign them and that would be a lot of work

Comment: That is the problem... The bulbs are placed already and i don't want to delete all of them and place them again.... I've also tried linking material but it only gives them material as you said but if there's a way to give material to correct faces.... There must be something, some mod or a way of doing it..... Please anyone else ???

Comment: Hi :). If your objects are simple duplicates, you can make them *linked duplicates*. That will also link the materials. https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/159820/78972

Comment: Thankyou Sooo mucchhhhh.....